# Saying Shirat Haberiah (song of creation) in Rosh Hashana

Tags: minhag, rosh-hashanah-new-year, perek-shira

In Masechet Rosh Hashanah 32 B: it is stated that "no poetry is said on Rosh Hashanah and on Yom Kippur". Is it possible to understand from this that it is not acceptable to say the song of creation ([Shirat Haberiah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perek_Shira)) on Rosh Hashanah?

Comment: In context, the "poetry" referred to in the gemara seems to be specifically Hallel. I'm not aware of any other songs/poetry that we are not supposed to recite on Rosh HaShanah.

Comment: What's Shirat Haberiah?

Comment: @Heshy he means Perek Shirah. I added a link.